# XML regular expression

Tags: xml

I just came around this expression:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_@$\-][!-~]*
```

And my question would be: what the expression `!-~` means in this context?

When I let this expression check in a text which characters fulfill this expression it selects every character.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks

Comment: How is your question related to XML? Where have you come around the expression?

Comment: You say "in this context", but you haven't told us what the context is.

Comment: FYI: There's a great tool for helping with regular expressions: https://regex101.com/.  Paste your regex in there and not only do you get to test it out against various strings, but in the right pane you get an explanation of what each bit does. "!-~ a single character in the range between ! (index 33) and ~ (index 126) (case sensitive)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the regex fragment `[!-~]*` means any sequence of zero or more characters whose numeric code is between x21 and x7E - that is, any sequence of ASCII characters other than space and DEL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael that was really helpful.